# Kivy: Window.clearcolor stops fullscreen mode

Tags: python, kivy

i am working with kivy on macOS. I tried to develop a fullscreen app with white background (kivy default seems to be black):

```
class TestApp(App):

 def build(self):
    label = Label(...)
    return label

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    app = TestApp()
    app.run()
```

After adding `Window.Clearcolor` the app only starts in a window, fullscreen does not work anymore. Does anyone know what's the issue with my code.

Comment: seems it has to do with `from kivy.core.window import Window`

Comment: From the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html#applying-configurations): "Configuration options control the initialization of the App. In order to avoid situations where the config settings do not work or are not applied before window creation (like setting an initial window size), Config.set should be used before importing any other Kivy modules. Ideally, this means setting them right at the start of your main.py script."

Comment: setting config before importing `kivy.core.window` works fine. Thanks for the hint.